# Error(66,3): PLS-00201: identifier must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, pls-00201

I have 1 procedure in with the user `CC_DEVICE` .
In this procedure I have this statement calling a procedure of another user.

```
of_device.p_msg.parse_csd_session(p_message);
```

But I got this error when compiling the package:

```
Error(66,3): PLS-00201: identifier 'OF_DEVICE.P_MSG' must be declared
```

Comment: You may not have permissions and need to grant it. With the `of_device` user run `GRANT EXECUTE ON of_device.p_msg TO your_current_user;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be granted to use that procedure with :

```
SQL> conn of_device/pwd1
SQL> grant execute on p_msg to cc_device
SQL> conn cc_device/pwd0
```

now you can use it from cc_device...